# How to open a file from script which is runniing at boot time

Tags: c, shell, u-boot

I am running my script file in u-boot. I want to create a file and save my contents.I tried the following ,

```
cat > info.txt <<- "EOF"        // opening the file
echo "${mmcpart}" | tee info.txt           // adding contents
echo "${root_fs}" | tee -a info.txt
EOF
```

and ,
    `echo "${mmcpart}" | tee info.txt        // directly adding the contents in`

file

```
echo "${root_fs}" | tee -a info.txt
```

Its not working.......... Can anyone help me to find out

Comment: Why the "c" flag? There is no C here.

Answer (score 2):

The u-boot doesn't support shell script syntax, u-boot has [hush shell](http://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/CommandLineParsing) and for reading file and manipulating environment variables you can follow [this](https://github.com/linux-sunxi/u-boot-sunxi/wiki)